# Possible exploit while MPLS parsing with Bottom of Stack bit

Tags: exploit, attack-prevention

My current task to parse MPLS label in a packet and store them in to a list.

When I check packets with MPLS:

[image]

One can understand it is the last MPLS header by checking Bottom of Stack bit. If this bit is 1, time to stop parsing.

Before starting parser implementation I wanted to ask if I should consider a attack like, someone in the middle just sets Bottom of Stack flag from 1 to 0 so application goes  parsing unrelatted packets as MPLS headers until application finds 1.

Is this a case worth to consider? 
If it is, a simple threshold check(won't check more headers after 10) will be enough or
more complicated design needs to be considered?